# useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-uselibrary

I am using `Android 1.5` (Win 8.1 x64), I forked the `DrKLO/Telegram` repository on `GitHub` and cloned it on my local machine. Now whenever I try to sync Gradle or clean/build project, the Gradle sync fails with this message:

> Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

**build.gradle** (Project: Telegram) [[DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/build.gradle](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/build.gradle)]

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
```

**build.gradle** (Module: TMessagesProj) [[DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle)]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.6.+'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    ...
}
```

I know there are many questions here, on StackOverflow, about this issue. But non of them have worked with me. I even tried some alternatives like copying the `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` file from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\optional` to the `libs` directory, and added it to the dependencies

```
compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
```

Although, I really dislike this solution, but it didn't work either and Gradle still fails ...

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Comment: @Sharath No, but I had to move to using [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) .

Comment: OK!I just found a solution for it thats why i asked to you!

Comment: @Sharath Good job! I encourage you to post it as an answer, as it may help others who faces this problem and looking for a solution.

Comment: Ya sure.added it as answer.Can you accept it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Locate your **org.apache.http.legacy.jar** file, usually it is in your SDK's platforms\android-xx\optional
2. Create **optional.json**
3. Paste the following:

   ```
   [
        {
       "name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
       "jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
       "manifest": false
      }
   ]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the jar is available from `mavenCentral()` instead try using `jcenter()`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Also you should try updating to the latest android gradle plugin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem even after adding jcenter()

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a Text file and name it as optional,file type as .json and add the following content:

```
[
  {
"name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
"jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
"manifest": false
  }
]
```

2.Add

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

in Gradle.properties file of your project.

Answer (score 0):

ONLY FOR THOSE WHO ARE LOOKING SOLUTION ON Android API 28!

`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` does not work on Android v9.0 API28. App crashes upon calling below lines..

```
`DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`
```

Just follow 2 simple steps

1. Put inside your AndroidManifest.xml the next line under  tag

   `<uses-library
           android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
           android:required="false" />`
2. Change your url from 'http' to 'https' which needs to be invoke

This worked for me.. even in the mid of 2020!